# Cant run adb process

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, android-emulator-plugin

I'm creating an application in android studio but I am um able test it on the virtual emulator because the adb process won't start. It's giving this error.

[image]
I tried manually starting adb and all other things but this happens.

[image]
I tried reinstalling android studio and platform tools. I downloaded a separate adb and ran "adb start-server"/"kill server".

It just doesn't seem to work. So i constantly have to build the entire thing and generate apk to run it. Please help me guys!!!
Also regarding the virtual emulator i have intel haxm installed if that information was necessary.

Comment: Check who occupied port 5037. Start > All Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Resource Monitor > Network > Listening Ports

Comment: Apparently nothing. Just checked it https://imgur.com/X1EgGhC

Answer (score 0):

It's may be because your emulator adb not allow the android studio to run on it and android studio try to stop and re-run but this process fail.

Me also the same problem. So i always follows this step and it's work for me.
1. Open android studio.
2. Try to run your app without opening your emulator(It will start your adb).
3. Then open your emulator and run your app.
 It's working for me. May solve your problem.

Comment: Tried it. Not working. It seems something is wrong with my PC. Might just try reinstalling windows. Cause also my network is giving issues.

Answer (score 0):

`adb server didnt ack`. This issue will resolve ussually when you kill all instances of `adb.exe` and restart server again.
Open Task manager and kill all adb instances and start server again.

Try the following:

- Close Studio.
- End adb.exe process in taskmanager.
- Issue kill and
- Run `adb kill-server`
- Run `adb devices`
- Then start the emulator and try `adb devices` again. This should list your emulator-device.
- Run you apk in studio.

Comment: I think you didn't read my question completely. Also look at the pics. I tried those commands. They aren't working. Also there isn't any adb process running to kill.

Answer (score -1):

If your are using Genymotion,try to link your Android Studio 's SDK to Genymotion Android SDK Path.Then try to type with `adb devices`, I hope this will help for you.
[image]